# Can you add SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1; to a view?

Tags: mysql

I need to set that before executing the query view. Only reason I am doing this is cause Bluehost won't add that to the server for some reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try SET SESSION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 before accessing the view

You cant 'execute' the view, its just a DDL statement which defines how MySQL should access the underlying tables